# Using a nested router or a child route

Tags: vuejs3

I have a view in which has a list of components, and these components are clickable. When clicked, they need to send an id to the following component. But first this is how I would like the flow to work.

[image]

I try it two different ways.

course compoent

```
<template>
    <div @click='showDetails' data-v-145c="" class="bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-700 relative h-full rounded-lg shadow-md mx-2">
        <div data-v-145c="" class="ribbon ribbon-top-right"></div>
        <div data-v-145c="" class="w-full">
            <div data-v-145c="" class="p-8 pr-16">
            <h1 data-v-145c="" class="font-extrabold mr-8 text-2xl">{{ props.course.title }}</h1>
        </div>
            <div data-v-145c="" class="flex px-8"><div data-v-145c="" class="w-2/3">
                <p data-v-145c="" class="text-sm text-gray-200">{{ props.course.desc }}</p>
            </div>
      .......
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const props = defineProps(['course']);
const router = useRouter();

const showDetails = () => {
    router.push({path: '/details', params: {id: props.course.id }}) <-- this seems not the best way to do this.
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

courses component

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import Course from "../components/courses/Course.vue";
import Filter from "../components/courses/Filter.vue";

const courses = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'The Course',
        desc: 'A crash course!',
        lessons: 1,
        duration: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'The Course',
        desc: 'A fun crash course!',
        lessons: 5,
        duration: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'The Course',
        desc: 'Another crash course!',
        lessons: 4,
        duration: 3,
    },
]
</script>

<template>

    <div class="flex grid-cols-2 justify-start">
        <div class="">
            <Filter/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 h-4 md:w-4/5 p-4">
            <div class="md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10" v-for='course in courses'>
                <Course :key="course.id" :course="course"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>


</style>
```

The other way unsuccessful way is to use routes.

```
{
    path: '/courses',
    meta: { title: 'Courses' },
    component: () => import('../views/Courses.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: "/details/:id",
            component: CourseDetail,
        }
    ]
},
```

The first way changes the view, but nothing renders, as the :id is not available. The second approach has no effect, but I think that is the way I should be trying to figure out.

Advice?

Comment: Nested routes require using `<router-view />` inside the parent component. If you don't need a unique URL for the child component - then you don't need nested routes. Simply provide the data through props of the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since (as I understand your drawing) you don't want to load the details in the list component, but replace the list by the details component, the details should not be a child of the course.

So change your routes to:

```
[
{
    path: '/courses',
    name: 'courses',
    meta: { title: 'Courses' },
    component: () => import('../views/Courses.vue'),
 },
 {
    path: "/courses/:id",
    name: 'courseDetails',
    component: CourseDetail,
 }
],
```

It is also good practice to name your routes and use that in instead of paths. So you can use `router.push({name: 'courseDetails', params: {id: props.course.id }})` to go to the details page.

Comment: This was the missing piece... Thank you very much!